# Changing models in django results in broken database?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have added and removed fields in my models.py file and then run manage.py syncdb. Usually I have to quit out of the shell and restart it before syncdb does anything. And then even after that, I am getting errors when trying to access the admin pages, it seems that certain new fields that I've added still don't show up in the model:

```
Caught an exception while rendering: no such column: mySite_book.Title
```

Answer (score 9):

Django does not perform database migration for you, i.e., if you add new fields, Django won't modify your database schema.

You can either:

1. Drop the tables that changed and perform syncdb again. This is reasonnable when you are developing your application and you don't have any real data in your database.
2. Use a migration tool like [South](http://south.aeracode.org/) that performs database migration (like hibernate update script).
3. Edit the database by hand and add/delete the appropriate fields for the previously existing tables.

Comment: I'm using SQLite, how do I drop the tables? Can it be done from django? Or do I need to connect through the SQLite command console? And if I drop the tables, will the syncdb automatically rebuild them when I run it again?

Comment: Yes, if you drop the table, syncdb will automatically rebuild them. You can use SQLite command console or one of the numerous gui tools such as: http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/ and http://sites.google.com/site/sqlitetool/

Answer (score 4):

For me, (so long as you're doing this with test data, and not doing this in a production environ) it's alot easier to just blow away the test.db and do a new ./manage.py syncdb. Just food for thought...

Answer (score 2):

Just to expand on @Barthelemy's answer, there are several [Django migration tools](http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/SchemaEvolution):

- [South](http://south.aeracode.org/)
- [Deseb](http://code.google.com/p/deseb/)
- [django-evolution](http://code.google.com/p/django-evolution/)
- [dmigrations](http://code.google.com/p/dmigrations/) (MySQL only)
- [nashvegas](http://paltman.com/2009/feb/24/nashvegas-a-simple-django-migration-tool/)
- [yadsel](http://code.google.com/p/yadsel)